# Skip 3 images in slider as the example

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Hello everyone, I'm trying, without much success, to reproduce this slider to skip 3 images at once, what I achieved here was to jump from 1 to 1 using SWIPER, a JS script to skip the slider, but I imagine there is an easier way to do it using the

Example of the code I'm using:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".slide-content", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 25,
  loop: true,
  centerSlide: "true",
  fade: "true",
  grabCursor: "true",
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    dynamicBullets: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },

  breakpoints: {
    0: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
    },
    520: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
    },
    950: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add slidesPerGroup attribute

```
slidesPerGroup="3"
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-react-slides-per-view-auto-forked-8n357s)

Comment: thank you so much friend for taking your time to answer me! it worked correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Add the

```
slidesPerGroup: 3
```

to your existing config and it should work

see an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-slides-per-view-forked-4s10vl?file=%2Findex.html&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A20%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A73%2C%22startColumn%22%3A20%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A73%7D%5D)

Comment: thanks a lot friend! it worked correctly i'm feeling dumb now, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

add `slidesPerGroup : 3`

read the docs here [SwiperJs SlidesPerGroup](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slidesPerGroup)